# Проблемы записи данных в список python

Tags: python, telebot

я разрабатываю телеграм бота на telebot python. И хочу сделать очистку данных чата для удобств пользывателя, но у меня проблема в том что из за записи данных в массив сообщения дальше не идут

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def store_message(message):
    # Получаем текст сообщения
    message_text = message.text

    # Добавляем сообщение в список
    messages.append(message_text)
```

и оно получается перехватывает сообщения,в конце пытался вставить но сообщение исчезает после другой функции. Посоветуйте альтернативу или способ решения проблемы